# Merging two tables into one both the table having different where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having Two Sql Queries as Follows:

1st Query

```
SELECT TC.TCName, 
sum(BS.BLDOS) as BLDOS,
sum(BS.CollectedAmount) as CollectedAmount, 
(0.35*sum(BS.BLDOS)) as TargetAmount
FROM [Customer] C 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[BillingStatus] BS ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TCDetails] TC ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID
WHERE TC.TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) 
                    FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] )
GROUP BY TCName 
order by [TCName] ASC
```

I am getting a result:

```
   ||TCName ||  BLDOS  || CollectedAmount || TargetAmount||
    | Aarti  |  81234.2 |    1678.76       |  789065     |
    | Dev    |  181234.2|     678.76       |  2389065    |
```

2nd query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] 
where TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] ) 
AND CallDate is NOT NULL 
GROUP BY TCName
```

AND I am Getting:

```
  ||count||
     231
     123
```

I want to print it like this

```
   ||TCName ||  BLDOS  || CollectedAmount || TargetAmount|| count ||
    | Aarti  |  81234.2 |    1678.76       |  789065     |   231   |
    | Dev    |  181234.2|     678.76       |  2389065    |   123   |
```

I am confused because both the queries are having different wheres clause

Comment: Au contraire - the `WHERE` clauses look to be practically identical. Also, `DISTINCT` within an `IN()` check is at best redundant and at worst, potentially harmful to performance.

Comment: Actually the IN clauses make no sense at all. Give me only records from table TCDetails that exists in table TCDetails???

Comment: What's the reason for adding [Customer] table when in both queries no records are to be selected from it?

Comment: @Deepshikha i will use them in future...

Comment: @Abhishek Singhal: Is TCName unique in TCDetails? Or TCName plus CustomerID? Or what combination is? And is CustomerID unique in BillingStatus or what combination is?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner CustomerID is unique as well as primary in all the tables...

Comment: add a case statement in count as shown below!!!

Comment: @Abhishek Singhal: Okay, then your statement can be simplified. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  * FROM 
(
SELECT TC.TCName, sum(BS.BLDOS) as BLDOS, sum(BS.CollectedAmount) as CollectedAmount, (0.35*sum(BS.BLDOS)) as TargetAmount
FROM [Customer] C INNER JOIN
     [dbo].[BillingStatus] BS ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID INNER JOIN
     [dbo].[TCDetails] TC ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID
WHERE TC.TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] )
GROUP BY TCName order by [TCName] ASC
) S JOIN
(
SELECT TCName,COUNT(*) as count FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] 
where TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] ) 
AND CallDate is NOT NULL GROUP BY TCName
) T ON S.TCName=T.TCName;
```

OP:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|TCName  |  BLDOS   | CollectedAmount  | TargetAmount| count   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Aarti  |  81234.2 |    1678.76       |  789065     |   231   |
| Dev    |  181234.2|     678.76       |  2389065    |   123   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You haven't looked closely. Both statements group by TCName.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes i have missed it. I have used Join now

Answer (score 1):

In both queries you use TCDetails and group by TCName. You don't have to do this twice only to count non-null call dates. COUNT(CallDate) does that for you. I also removed the IN clause which doesn't add anthing to your query. So the query is simply:

```
SELECT 
  TC.TCName, 
  sum(BS.BLDOS) as BLDOS, 
  sum(BS.CollectedAmount) as CollectedAmount, 
  0.35 * sum(BS.BLDOS) as TargetAmount,
  count(TC.CallDate) as cnt
FROM [Customer] C 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[BillingStatus] BS ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TCDetails] TC ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID
GROUP BY TC.TCName 
ORDER BY TC.TCName ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TC.TCName, sum(BS.BLDOS) as BLDOS, sum(BS.CollectedAmount) as CollectedAmount, (0.35*sum(BS.BLDOS)) as TargetAmount ,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] TC2
                 where TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] ) 
                  AND CallDate is NOT NULL AND TC2.TCName = TC.TCName GROUP BY TCName) AS Count
 FROM [Customer] C 
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[BillingStatus] BS
          ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[TCDetails] TC 
          ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID
     WHERE TC.TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] )
     GROUP BY TCName order by [TCName] ASC
```

Comment: I already tried this Getting ERROR 
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression".

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
SELECT  S.*,T.count FROM 
(
SELECT TC.TCName, sum(BS.BLDOS) as BLDOS, sum(BS.CollectedAmount) as CollectedAmount, (0.35*sum(BS.BLDOS)) as TargetAmount
FROM [Customer] C JOIN
     [dbo].[BillingStatus] BS ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID JOIN
     [dbo].[TCDetails] TC ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID
WHERE TC.TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] )
GROUP BY TCName order by [TCName] ASC
) S join 
(
SELECT TCName,COUNT(*) as count FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] 
where TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] ) 
AND CallDate is NOT NULL GROUP BY TCName
) T on S.TCName=T.TCName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as:

```
SELECT TC.TCName, 
       sum(BS.BLDOS) as BLDOS,
       sum(BS.CollectedAmount) as CollectedAmount, 
       (0.35*sum(BS.BLDOS)) as TargetAmount,
       Count(CallDate) as count
FROM [Customer] C 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[BillingStatus] BS ON BS.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TCDetails] TC ON TC.CustomerID = BS.CustomerID
WHERE TC.TCName in (Select distinct(TCName) 
                    FROM [dbo].[TCDetails] )
                    GROUP BY TCName 
order by [TCName] ASC
```

[Check Demo here.](http://rextester.com/CMG9806)

Comment: That doesn't work as you expect it to. I guess you meant to use SUM? Count(value) counts non-null values. As both 1 and 0 are non-null, you actually count(\*) in your statement.